# FTPing the National Centers for Biotechnology Information (NCBI)

Tags: data-request, data.gov

I am trying to ftp to the NCBI to download some information. Upon connecting I recieve, I get this warning message.

> Warning Notice!    You are accessing a U.S. Government information
>   system which includes this  computer, network, and all attached
>   devices. This system is for  Government-authorized use only.
>   Unauthorized use of this system may result in  disciplinary action and
>   civil and criminal penalties. System users have no  expectation of
>   privacy regarding any communications or data processed by this 
>   system. At any time, the government may monitor, record, or seize any 
>   communication or data transiting or stored on this information system.

What constitutes unauthorized access? Is it illegal for a US citizen to download information from the NCBI? What does this mean?

EDIT:

Below is the command I entered

```
ftp ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov
```

Comment: whats the ftp link?

Comment: I edited the post to show the link

Comment: word. i can't replicate it...no worries. want to say you're fine, but without confirmation, i know that is no help. made an inquiry, well share response.

Comment: @albert That is weird tho :/

Comment: na, i see stuff like that on the regular. probably a hold over from legacy system or something. i want to say your golden, they advertise ftp site https://twitter.com/NCBI/status/743782504566505472

Comment: @albert Awesome! That is conforting